# How to measure TCP latency?

Tags: networking, tcp, nmap, latency

OS is Debian on both servers.

I found some examples showing how to measure TCP latency with nmap:

```
nmap --packet-trace -p 22 192.168.0.10
```

But I'm getting some negative results for latency. ie, it will print some output like:

`Host is up (-0.0023s latency)`

at the end.

What is nmap doing? Is it measuring the time difference between SYN and SYN-ACK? If so, how is it getting a negative result sometimes? Does it require clocks to be very precisely synced between the two servers?

And in addition, can I use ssh as a good TCP test server or should I use a different service?

Is there another tool I can use to measure TCP latency? I don't know if I trust nmap due to the negative results for the latency measurement.

Answer (score 0):

You're right to mistrust things that claim to have witnessed time travel.

This is [an event confusion bug](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/issues/863), fixed in a later version of
Nmap. You might want to use a more recent nmap, but it's certainly not trust-inspiring.

But generally, it is also not quite clear what you mean with "TCP latency". That term isn't canonically defined; you'll want to, really, in words, write down which time exactly, from what event happening on which interface at what logical layer, to which other event, you want to measure. Only *after* having defined that would you choose a tool to measure that.

To give you an example: for anything that I would care to call "TCP-induced latency", I'd need to be able to determine timing both on the kernel/Userland interface, as well as on the driver/hardware interface - so a program that runs in Userland (like nmap) couldn't even begin to be what I need.

That doesn't mean that is true for what *you* want to measure, it just means you need to be precise about what you need to know, and to what end you need to know that. This is basically physics research, where you first need to think about what you want to observe, before devising an experiment to observe that, and in that experiment design process then decide on the right measurement equipment fir this purpose. Can't just throw a multimeter into a volcano and call it science!

Comment: Thank you! Good to know about that nmap bug. I would like to measure the time difference between SYN and SYN-ACK.

Comment: You did not answer any of the questions I specifically explained you need to answer.

Comment: What am I missing? Time difference between when userland program (nmap or other) sends a SYN and receives a SYN-ACK seems fairly straightforward.

Comment: A Userland program never sends syn or receives a syn ack. That happens on layers below! A Userland process calls functions like "connect" or "accept", and you'll find that there's a lot happening between these and any IP packets, which is very relevant to latency. Or not.  So it's really not straightforward, because what you ask for simply doesn't happen. What you need to measure Depends on what you actually need to know. That's why I specifically asked you to describe what the purpose of learning that time is.

Comment: Sure, I get that. Whenever the userland program is able to "detect" the syn-ack from whatever layers, via abstracted syscalls eventually returning, I don't care. I want to measure round trip tcp latency in terms of userland. I'm not exactly trying to count clock cycles here. That is implied by the fact that my original question is asking about a userland program. So userland makes a function call that *eventually* triggers a syn, start the clock in userland function call. Then syn-ack is returned, and via whatever method userland can "detect" the SYN-ACK, stop the clock, measure the time diff.

Comment: I don't understand - userland doesnt see that round-trip latency ever, because userland can't detect the syn-ack, or the syn+ack/ack, whichever your stacks are doing. You can count the time from the "connect" call entering until it returns control to the userland program, but in a local network you'd mostly be measuring the time that it takes to give control from the Userland to the kernel, and then from the kernel back to the Userland, because that takes **much** longer that the bit of state machine code in the kernel. So it's not clear to me what that latency has to do with TCP!

Comment: And that's why I'm again asking to what end, for what purpose you need that number. What will you do with it, once you make a good measurement? What's the purpose of measuring this? Is there a decision you want to make based on this?

Comment: nmap has shown userland round trip tcp latency of ~10 ms for some servers, but not others. There is no load on any of the servers and they are all on the same subnet, including the source server that I'm running nmap tests on. Why do some servers show a tcp latency of ~10 ms while most show sub ms? But the first step is to get an accurate measurement, and due to occasionally seeing negative latency from nmap, I don't know if I can trust the output.

Comment: Nice! This actually gives us an indication for what you're looking for! The nmap times are from a kernel side tracer, probably (it's libpcap on modern kernels), so I'm happy I persistently kept asking and we're not going with the end-to-end userland latency, because that would have been a very different and hence confusing thing - as said, it incorporates the context switches and the scheduling delay and would hence easily randomly end up in the multiple additional milliseconds, and you don't *actually* seem to care about the end-to-end latency, but about what is up with these servers.

Comment: What is the problem you were diagnosing with the nmap measurement? Why did you run it?